# How to use gcc to compile multiple files

Tags: gcc

I have several files needed to be compiled.
here is the command. the sample_client.c dependent on the lsp.o. Now I changed the lsp.c and lsp.h. How can I compile to get this change effective to lsp.o?

the main function is in the sample_client.c, lsp.c does not have a main function.

```
gcc -g -I/usr/include -g sample_client.c lsp.o lspmessage.pb-c.o -o sample_client -L/usr/lib -lprotobuf-c
```

Here is my makefile,

```
CC = gcc

TARGET = sample_client sample_server

CFLAGS += -g -I/usr/include
LDFLAGS += -g -lprotobuf-c -L/usr/lib

all:    $(TARGET)

$(TARGET):  lsp.o lspmessage.pb-c.o

%.o:    %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f *.o 
    rm -f $(TARGET)
```

However, the lprotobuf-c can not be correctly linked.

run make -f Makefile
I can get the following,

```
lspmessage.pb-c.o: In function `lspmessage__get_packed_size':
...: undefined reference to `protobuf_c_message_get_packed_size'
lspmessage.pb-c.o: In function `lspmessage__pack':
...: undefined reference to `protobuf_c_message_pack'
```

I know that I can run this command,

gcc -g -I/usr/include -g sample_client.c lsp.o lspmessage.pb-c.o -o sample_client -L/usr/lib -lprotobuf-c

But what if I change the lsp.c and lsp.h ?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to use makefile. I updated my question with makefile. Sorry, I am not familiar with this.

Comment: try harder because that's the way to do it

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your `LDFLAGS` isn't correct. Try the following:

```
LDFLAGS +=  -L/usr/lib -lprotobuf-c
```

It looks like you had the directory `-L` and the library out of order.

Also, I removed the additional call to `-g` for you.

Comment: It does not work. I think problem is not here. Thanks all the same.